# Intent won't recognize Activity

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-layout, firebase-realtime-database

In my recipe app the intent won't recognize any of my activities, the activity loads in the app but intent can't recognize it, also when i run the app the image won't show up in the recycler view, i suspect that intent isn't passing the data on since it cannot recognize any of my activities, the image was uploaded to my FireBase but it won't show in the recycler view when i run the app.

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.recipeapp, PID: 12376
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=class com.example.recipeapp.DetailActivity (has extras) }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2051)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1709)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5192)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5150)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5521)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5489)
        at com.example.recipeapp.MyAdapter$1.onClick(MyAdapter.java:59)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Activity_Detail.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".DetailActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivImage2"
        android:src="@drawable/feijoada"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/description_feijoada"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

DetailActivity:

```
package com.example.recipeapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView foodDescription;
    ImageView foodImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        foodDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        foodImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage2);

        Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (mBundle != null) {

            foodDescription.setText(mBundle.getString("Description"));
            foodImage.setImageResource(mBundle.getInt("Image"));

            Glide.with(this)
            .load(mBundle.getString("Image"))
            .into(foodImage);
        }
    }
}
```

MyAdapter:

```
package com.example.recipeapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<FoodData> myFoodList;

    public MyAdapter(Context mContext, List<FoodData> myFoodList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.myFoodList = myFoodList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FoodViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new FoodViewHolder(mView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final FoodViewHolder foodViewHolder, int i) {

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(myFoodList.get(i).getItemName())
                .into(foodViewHolder.imageView);


        //foodViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(myFoodList.get(i).getItemImage());
        foodViewHolder.mTitle.setText(myFoodList.get(i).getItemName());
        foodViewHolder.mDescription.setText(myFoodList.get(i).getItemDescription());
        foodViewHolder.mPrice.setText(myFoodList.get(i).getItemPrice());

        foodViewHolder.mCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(String.valueOf(DetailActivity.class));
                intent.putExtra("Image", myFoodList.get(foodViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemImage());
                intent.putExtra("Description", myFoodList.get(foodViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getItemDescription());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myFoodList.size();
    }

    public void filteredList(ArrayList<FoodData> filterList) {

        myFoodList = filterList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}

class FoodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView mTitle, mDescription, mPrice;
    CardView mCardView;

    public FoodViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        mDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
        mPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);

        mCardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myCardView);
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.recipeapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    List<FoodData> myFoodList;
    FoodData mFoodData;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    EditText txt_search;

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    private ValueEventListener eventListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 1);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        txt_search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_searchtext);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Carregando Itens...");

        myFoodList = new ArrayList<>();

        final MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, myFoodList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Recipe");

        progressDialog.show();

        eventListener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                myFoodList.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot itemSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    FoodData foodData = itemSnapshot.getValue(FoodData.class);
                    myFoodList.add(foodData);
                }

                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

        txt_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                filter(s.toString());

            }
        });

    }

    private void filter(String text) {

        ArrayList<FoodData> filterList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (FoodData item : myFoodList) {

            if (item.getItemName().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())) ;
            {

                filterList.add(item);

            }

        }

        myAdapter.filteredList(filterList);

    }


    public void btn_uploadActivity(View view) {

        startActivity(new Intent(this, Upload_Recipe.class));

    }
}
```

Upload_Recipe:

```
package com.example.recipeapp;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Upload_Recipe extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView recipeImage;
    Uri uri;
    EditText txt_name, txt_description, txt_price;
    String imageUrl;
    Object progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload__recipe);

        recipeImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_foodImage);
        txt_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_recipe_name);
        txt_description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_description);
        txt_price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_price);


    }

    public void btnSelectImage(View view) {

        Intent photoPicker = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPicker.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPicker, 1);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            uri = data.getData();
            recipeImage.setImageURI(uri);

        } else Toast.makeText(this, "Você não selecionou uma imagem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void uploadImage() {

        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("RecipeImage")
                .child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

        storageReference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                while (!uriTask.isComplete()) ;
                Uri urlImage = uriTask.getResult();
                if (urlImage != null) {
                    imageUrl = urlImage.toString();
                }
                uploadRecipe();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            }
        });
    }

    public void btnUploadRecipe(View view) {

        uploadImage();

    }

    public void uploadRecipe() {

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Enviando Receita...");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        finish();

        FoodData foodData = new FoodData(txt_name.getText().toString()
                , txt_description.getText().toString(), txt_price.getText().toString()
                , imageUrl);

        String myCurrentDateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()
                .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("Recipe")
                .child(myCurrentDateTime).setValue(foodData).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    Toast.makeText(Upload_Recipe.this, "Receita Enviada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();

                }

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(Upload_Recipe.this, "Falha ao Enviar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    private void ProgressDialog(Object progressDialog) {
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
        ProgressDialog(progressDialog);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are they declared in your manifest?

Comment: Yes they are but intent won't find them.

Comment: Please show intent code and database structure

Comment: It's in MyAdpater that i've just included, take a read.

Comment: And i also included MainActivity code.

Comment: @JúlioSordi does your adapter shows data ?

Comment: Yes it shows name description and price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to add an answer with an explanation.

When you are constructing your `Intent` inside `MyAdapter`, you provide a `String` parameter thus invoking the following constructor:

```java
public Intent(String action) {
    // code
}
```

Your code suggests that what you really mean is to invoke this constructor:

```java
public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) {
    // code
}
```

So, to launch your `DetailActivity` use this code:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
```

Also, note that keeping a reference to an Activity is generally discouraged.

Regarding the image, you are trying to load the **name** as the image:

```java
Glide.with(mContext)
     .load(myFoodList.get(i).getItemName())
     .into(foodViewHolder.imageView);
```

Comment: Thank you the intent is working now, regarding the image how can i fix it? i've uploaded the recipe with the image name description and price to FireBase but the image won't show up in the recipe list.

Comment: To load the image you should use `.load(myFoodList.get(i).getItemImageUrl())` or something like it, depending on where you store the image URL on the `FoodData` class.

Comment: Also, if the problem is resolved please accept an answer because people keep investing time and effort to provide more answers.

Comment: i think the image is stored somewhere in Recipe_Upload, i've just edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
Intent intent = new Intent(String.valueOf(DetailActivity.class));
```

with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

`Intent intent = new Intent(String.valueOf(DetailActivity.class));`

I think you need to read the doc about Intent.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#public-constructors

Take a look at the constructor that takes a String as its argument.

You are creating an Intent which requires any activity that can resolve an ACTION, not an Intent which requires a DetailActivity

Should be

`Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);`

And see the error message:

`No Activity found to handle Intent { act=class com.example.recipeapp.DetailActivity (has extras) }`

act stand for ACTION